# Extension lemma for measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Lemma 2.1.4 on [Knill's book](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/books/KnillProbability.pdf) states the following: if $\mathcal{I}\subset \Omega$ is a $\pi$-system and $\mu, \nu$ are measures on $(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{I}))$ such that $\mu(\Omega),\nu(\Omega) < \infty$ and $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for every $A\in \mathcal{I}$, then $\mu = \nu$. Now, the proof consists in defining $\mathcal{D}:=\{A \in \sigma(\mathcal{I}): \hspace{0.1cm} \mu(A) = \nu(A)\}$ and show this is a Dynkin system. The first property of a Dynkin system is that it must contain $\Omega$, but I don't see why does $\Omega \in \mathcal{D}$ from the hypotheses. Any help?

*Note*: A $\pi$-system is just a (non-empty) set of subsets of $\Omega$ which is closed under finite intersections.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is implied by the given statements. Since we start off by saying:

> $\mu, \nu$ are measures on $(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{I}))$ such that $\mu(\Omega),\nu(\Omega) < \infty$

It is implied that $\Omega \in \sigma(\mathcal{I})$.

Comment: Hello Scott! It is true that $\Omega \in \sigma(\mathcal{I})$ but why does it belong to $\mathcal{D}$. One must have $\mu(\Omega)=\nu(\Omega)$.

Comment: We do have $\mu(\Omega) = v(\Omega)$ because $\mu(A) = v(A)$ for every $A \in I$

edit: wait nvm, sorry, thats not quite right

Comment: Yes, but we don't know if $\Omega \in \mathcal{I}$, right? We only know that $\Omega \in \sigma(\mathcal{I})$ because it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I was reading the wikipedia proof (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system) which assumed that  $\mu(\Omega) = v(\Omega)$

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I didn't know this was mentioned in wikipedia. It seems natural to consider $\mu(\Omega)=\nu(\Omega)<\infty$ tho.

Comment: I think we must have the wikipedia assumption because otherwise, we could construct a pi system and measures $\mu,v$ as so:

$I = \{A, \emptyset\}$
$\sigma(I) = \{A, A^c, \emptyset, \Omega\}$

$\mu(A) = 4, \mu(\emptyset)=0, \mu(\Omega)=10$, $v(A)=4, v(\emptyset)=0, v(\Omega)=100$

Clearly, $\mu$ and $v$ agree on $I$, and they are finite measures, but they do not agree on $\sigma(I)$

Comment: also, $A \cup A^c = \Omega$ in my counterexample